# Commutation fo a self-adjoint operator with a unitary operator

Tags: operator-theory, unitary-representations

Let $A$ be a selfadjoint bounded operator on a Hilbert space. Let $M$ be another bounded selfadjoint operator. Let me assume the commutation property 
$$
[A, e^{iM}]=0.
\tag 1$$
Does (1) imply that 
$$
[A, M]=0?
\tag 2$$
Is there a version of this for $M$ unbounded? I guess that something should be said on the domain of the unbounded $M$. Are the above properties obvious (positively or negatively) in finite dimension?

Comment: In finite dimension, two diagonalizable operators commute iff there is a basis in which they are both diagonal. So in finite dimensuion your (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Not quite: Let $M$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $2\pi$ und $-2\pi$, and let $A$ be any matrix that does not commute with $M$.

Comment: As is so often the case, the counterexample suggests what is going wrong here.  The general problem would be the question: if $A$ and $f(M)$ commute, is the same true of $A$ and $M$?  So what you need  is that $f$ be invertible in a suitable sense. It is easy to formulate a precise version which I will leave as an exercise to the OP since I am typing this on a pad.

Comment: To sum up the discussion so far, this will work (for arbitrary $A$) if and only if $e^{ix}$ is injective on $x\in\sigma(M)$ (because then $M$ is a function of $e^{iM}$, and if you don't have this condition, then there's Jochen's counterexample).